# Question about John Lee's proof of Fundamental Theorem for Nonautonomous ODEs by using the result for autonomous ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

The following is from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds that gives the proof to the Fundamental theorem for nonautonomous ODEs. The proof is given in Theorem D.6 below, and it uses Theorem D.1, which is the Fundamental theorem for autonomous ODEs and extend it to cover the nonautonomous case. However, I cannot see how this proof actually works.  It says in the proof that Theorem D.1 guarantees that there is an interval $J_0 \subset \mathbb{R}$ containing $s_0$ and an open subset $W_0 \subset J \times U$ containing $(s_0,x_0)$, such that for any $(t_0,c)\in W_0$ there exists a unique solution to (D.20) defined for $t\in J_0$, and the solution depends smoothly on $(t,t_0,c)$.

However, if you look at the statement of Theorem D.1, the domain of $V$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the open subset $W_0$ is also a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and so I cannot see how Theorem D.1 applies here. I can see that by the first statement of the proof, we only need to solve for $y^1, \dots, y^n$, however, $V^i$ in (D.20), is a function with $n+1$ inputs, or with the domain contained in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so I really cannot see how Theorem D.1 guarantees a solution. I would greatly appreciate some help. understanding this modification.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to augment the dimension of $V$. Replace $V = (V^1,\ldots,V^n)$ with $V = (V^0,V^1,\ldots,V^n)$, where
$$
V^0 = V^0(y^0(t),\ldots,y^n(t)) = 1.
$$
Also set $c^0 = y^0(t_0) = t_0$. Then for $i=0,\ldots,n$ we have
$$
\dot{y}^i(t) = V^i(y_0(t),\ldots,y^n(t)),~~~ y^i(t_0) = c^i.
$$
Now we're in the setting of Theorem D.1, with $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ replaced by $J\times U \subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $V:J\times U\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and $c = (c^0,\ldots,c^n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.